# How does TypeScript type "unknown" in a function which wants to return a specific type

Tags: typescript

I guess in general this question has to do with how typescript is parsing types in runtime

Specifically
I have a function that returns values from some JSON.

The function is signed like this:

`function getValueForKey(key: string): unknown;`

Now, I've defined my own type like this which I want to work against in a safe manner:

```
type Book = {
 title: string;
 headline: string;
 bullets: string[];
 author?: string; 
}
```

and an additional function that wants to return a `Book` from this `JSON` or `default` if the value doesn't exist or also if the value is incorrectly formatted per my requirement.

```
const defaultBook: Book = {
  title: "my book",
  author: "me",
  bullets: ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
}

function getBook(): Book {
  const book = getValueForKey("book"); // this could be null, or something which abides to a "Book" type or perhaps something which is not a book
  // how do I check if book is a "Book" type (abides by Book type) 

}
```

How do I ensure this is parsed/handled correctly?

Is this the correct mechanism to handle that? How is the runtime checking this ?

```
const book : Book | null = getValueForKey("book");
```

Comment: FWIW if you decided to go the [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) route: https://tsplay.dev/wEBjyN